# commandButton does not invoke bean action method

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2

Im having a big issue with JSF2 render actions.
Im using a simple c:forEach to iterate over a List. This list has itens and those items has a List of more Itens. So its a nested c:forEach. The sub list has an input field that, once saved, has to go to the bean, save this new input, and get back to the screen with the updated List.
Nothing complex to do. When i debug the method that sends the List back to the view, i see that all the information is correct.
So here we go with the issue : The first time the commandButton works fine. But if i try to click on another button on the list just after it was refreshed, the button does not call my method. Whats wierd is that the action does sends it to the bean (it goes thru my @PostConstruct method), but does not call the method i want.

The code :

```
 <c:forEach var="pub" items="${publicacaoCidadeController.listaPublicacao}" varStatus="status">
        <div>message from first list : ${status.count} <br/>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{pub.publicacao.mensagem}" />
            <br/><br/>message from second list :<br/>
            <h:form>
            <f:ajax event="action" execute="@form" render="@all">
            <c:forEach id="test2" var="com" items="#{pub.publicacao.comentarioList}" >                                 
                <div>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{com.mensagem}" />
                </div>                                
            </c:forEach> 
            <div>
            <h:inputTextarea value="#{publicacaoCidadeController.msgComentarioNovo}" />
            <div >                                    
                    <h:commandButton type="submit" value="Postar" action="#{publicacaoCidadeController.salvarComentario}" >
                        <f:param name="codPublicacao" value="#{pub.publicacao.codPublicacao}"/>
                        <f:param name="postNum" value="${status.count}"/>
                    </h:commandButton>
                </div>                                     
                </div>
                </f:ajax>
                </h:form>              
            </div>
    </c:forEach>
```

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `ui:repeat` tag.
`c:foreach` is a build-view-tag and `ui:repeat` is a render-tag.
After pressing the command button the jsf-tree isn't rebuild ...

If you include the `ui:debug` tag, you can consult the de jsf-tree and investigate what's going on....

Comment: Hi, just to let you know, you can highlight sections of text as `code` using backticks ( ``` ), that generally makes questions easier to read.